# Reading data (embedded plist) linked to executable through -sectcreate __TEXT

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker

I am linking a executable with a plist using `-sectcreate __TEXT` linker flags. Reason for this is mainly to use the SMJobBless() method. But I need to read plist linked from another application. This is only because I need to install the same privileged application on a 10.5 system and I can’t use SMJobBless() on 10.5.

How do I read this linked plist using Objective-C so I can copy it to /Library/LaunchDaemons/ myself?

Comment: In case you haven’t seen the updated answer, I’ve released [BVPlistExtractor](https://github.com/bavarious/BVPlistExtractor).

Comment: @Bavarious Thanks! BVPlistExtractor is perfect.

Comment: I cloned @Bavarious repo at: https://github.com/ETroll/BVPlistExtractor for those still looking for this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## otool

You can use otool(1) to dump the contents of the section containing the embedded plist:

```
otool -s __TEXT __info_plist /path/to/executable
```

and then pipe its output to xxd(1) in order to obtain the corresponding ASCII representation:

```
otool -X -s __TEXT __info_plist /path/to/executable | xxd -r
```

However, [otool is only available in machines where Xcode has been installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28110/5077).

## NSBundle

For the cases where a program needs to read its own embedded plist, NSBundle can be used:

```
id someValue = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:someKey];
```

## Mach-O

For the cases where a program needs to read the embedded plist of an arbitrary file without resorting to otool, the program can parse the Mach-O information in the file and extract its embedded plist as follows:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mach-o/loader.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

id embeddedPlist(NSURL *executableURL) {
    id plist = nil;
    int fd;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    size_t size;

    char *addr = NULL;
    char *start_addr = NULL;
    struct mach_header_64 *mh = NULL;
    struct load_command *lc = NULL;
    struct segment_command_64 *sc = NULL;
    struct section_64 *sect = NULL;

    // Open the file and get its size
    fd = open([[executableURL path] UTF8String], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) goto END_FUNCTION;
    if (fstat(fd, &stat_buf) == -1) goto END_FILE;
    size = stat_buf.st_size;

    // Map the file to memory
    addr = start_addr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) goto END_FILE;

    // The first bytes are the Mach-O header
    mh = (struct mach_header_64 *)addr;

    // Load commands follow the header
    addr += sizeof(struct mach_header_64);

    for (int icmd = 0; icmd < mh->ncmds; icmd++) {
        lc = (struct load_command *)addr;

        if (lc->cmd != LC_SEGMENT_64) {
            addr += lc->cmdsize;
            continue;
        }

        if (lc->cmdsize == 0) continue;

        // It's a 64-bit segment
        sc = (struct segment_command_64 *)addr;

        if (strcmp("__TEXT", sc->segname) != 0 || sc->nsects == 0) {
            addr += lc->cmdsize;
            continue;
        }

        // It's the __TEXT segment and it has at least one section
        // Section data follows segment data
        addr += sizeof(struct segment_command_64);
        for (int isect = 0; isect < sc->nsects; isect++) {
            sect = (struct section_64 *)addr;
            addr += sizeof(struct section_64);

            if (strcmp("__info_plist", sect->sectname) != 0) continue;

            // It's the __TEXT __info_plist section
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(start_addr + sect->offset)
                                          length:sect->size];
            plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                              options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                               format:NULL
                                                                error:NULL];
            goto END_MMAP;
        }
    }

END_MMAP:
    munmap(addr, size);

END_FILE:
    close(fd);

END_FUNCTION:
    return plist;
}
```

and:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/some/file"];
id plist = embeddedPlist(url);
if ([plist isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *info = plist;
    id someValue = [info objectForKey:someKey];
}
```

Note that `embeddedPlist()` has some limitations: it expects the file to be a thin Mach-O file (i.e., it will crash with non-Mach-O files and it won’t work with fat files containing, for example, both i386 and x86_64 Mach-O data); it only works with x86_64 files; it doesn’t report errors.

I went ahead and released [BVPlistExtractor](https://github.com/bavarious/BVPlistExtractor) under the MIT licence. It detects whether the file is indeed a thin Mach-O file or a fat/universal file, and works with both i386 and x86_64.

Comment: What happens when you create an NSBundle for an executable file (as opposed to getting the main “bundle” for your own executable)?

Comment: @Peter `+[NSBundle bundleWith…:]` returns `nil` for standalone executable files.

Comment: I've updated your post to add the -X option when piping to xxd since without removing the headers you'll get corrupted data which you may not immediately notice (i.e. something like `<?xml ve.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`).

Comment: There's a typo in this implementation.  munmap is called on addr instead of start_addr resulting in a leak.

Comment: man getsectdata looks like it can replace that entire section of code with something very simple.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use the method posted by adno, it seems to be the official API for this use case (and should be the accepted answer).

Comment: `otool -P binary` prints the contents of the __TEXT __info_plist section. If you want to use otool, use `otool -P`. (Useful for debugging, not useful for doign this from code.)

Comment: The link to BVPlistExtractor doesn't seem to work anymore. This one does, though https://github.com/ETroll/BVPlistExtractor

Comment: @thakis is right, the mentioned otool command is no longer working. You have to use `otool -P ./binary` now, that's it.

Answer (score 18):

There's a CoreFoundation function for that: `CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryForURL()`. From the documentation:

> For a directory URL, this is equivalent to `CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryInDirectory`. For a plain file URL representing an unbundled application, this function will attempt to read an information dictionary either from the (`__TEXT`, `__info_plist`) section of the file (for a Mach-O file) or from a `plst` resource.

It's available on Mac OS X v10.2 and later. If you use in Cocoa you can do this (provided you have an `(NSURL*)url` for the bundle):

```c
NSDictionary* infoPlist = [ (NSDictionary*) CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryForURL( (CFURLRef) url ) autorelease];
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work for me on 10.11.5. The embeddedPlist() function above did (unmodified).

Comment: @kainjow `CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryForURL` works for me (macOS 10.14).

Answer (score 7):

User's computer would not probably have `otool` installed, and I had the same problem. The solution was to use `launchctl`, which is guaranteed to be present at any modern Mac.

It has a `plist` subcommand which does the following:

```
Prints the the property list embedded in the __TEXT,__info_plist segment/section
of the target Mach-O or the specified segment/section.
```

If you do not specify the section, it prints __TEXT by default. The only argument to provide is the path to the executable:

`launchctl plist /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.sparklabs.ViscosityHelper`

If you have given path, output might be something like this:

```
{
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.sparklabs.ViscosityHelper";
    "SMAuthorizedClients" = (
        "anchor apple generic and identifier "com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity" and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] /* exists */ or certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = "34XR7GXFPX")";
    );
    "CFBundleName" = "ViscosityHelper";
    "CFBundleVersion" = "548";
    "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion" = "6.0";
};
```

It can be used in command-line as well as from code via `NSTask` (`Process` in swift) class.

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler approach:

```
#include <mach-o/getsect.h>

unsigned long *len;
char *data = getsectdata("__TEXT", "__info_plist");
```

man getsectdata.  There's lots of examples on how to access various pieces (current executable, arbitrary executable, framework, etc).

Comment: `getsectdata()` doesn't seem to work well or maybe at all on recent systems—apparently, it doesn't account for ASLR or something.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28978788/291280) uses `getsectiondata()`, which accounts for that.

Answer (score 3):

Since the otool command from the accepted answer does not seem to work anymore (produces gibberish on macOS Monterey), here is how you can still read an embedded Info.plist from a mach-o on the command line:

```
otool -P ./binary
```

From the man pages:

```
 -P     Print the info plist section, (__TEXT,__info_plist), as strings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the original question I needed to read info and launchd property lists embedded in an executable with `-sectcreate __TEXT`. As it's 2021 I'm using Swift, but couldn't find anything existing to meet my needs. It took me a bit to figure out how, so I decided to package it up: [EmbeddedPropertyList](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/EmbeddedPropertyList).

If you run into any issues using it, either reply here on open an issue on Github.