# Adding version infomation to an OSX command line application

Tags: command-line, osx-snow-leopard, versioning, osx-lion

On Windows I'd simply add an RC file with the right data. Do I need to assemble a bundle as usual with an info.plist/version.plist or is there a better, *standard*, way of doing things? This is for Snow Leopard and later if that is relevant.

Thx++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to embed an Info.plist file in an executable as a special Mach-o section.  See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797773/retrieve-info-plist-file-from-command-line-tool).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a command line application, then it's just a single file and not a traditional OSX app package (with a Contents folder and a MacOS + Resources folder underneath).

If you're not willing to do a full blown Macintosh application package (with a GUI and an info.plist embedded somewhere in there), there are a few different things I've seen done with command line apps on the Macintosh.

## 1)

Add a "-v" option for version. So if you app is named foo, typing in "`foo -v`" at the command line shows an output of "`version 1.0`".

## 2)

Put the version number in as part of the filename... so "foo" is actually "foo1.0".

Oof, that seems clunky. So...

## 3)

Some apps have a symbolic link pointing to the real binary.  So `foo` points to `foo1.0` and if you were to do a "ls -l", you'd see something like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    66128 Jul 12 15:39 foo1.0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       15 Jul 12 15:39 foo -> foo1.0
```

so typing in "foo" at the command line would actually run foo1.0.

I hope these opinions help you out!

Comment: Michael, thanks - I'm trying to automate this all for building. Perhaps I should have made that clearer in the question