# Swift application has no version?

Tags: swift, plist, versioning

I am trying to get my app version, after following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965239/how-do-i-get-the-app-version-and-build-number-using-swift) I tried this code :

```
import foundation
var config: [String: Any]?

if let infoPlistPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Info", withExtension: "plist") {
    do {
        let infoPlistData = try Data(contentsOf: infoPlistPath)
        
        if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: infoPlistData, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: Any] {
            config = dict
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

print(config?["CFBundleName"])
// Optional(example-info)

print(config?["CFBundleVersion"])
// Optional(1)

print(config?["CFBundleShortVersionString"])
// Optional(1.0)
```

but I get always nil as a result.

Does that mean that my app has no version? If so how to set a version to it?

In addition, when I investigate the Info.plist file with Xcode I found that it's empty!

Comment: Are you building an .app bundle, or a command line tool? Did you specify the `Info.plist` file (Xcode does this by default when creating new app).

Comment: I am building a command line tool

Comment: That's the cause of your problem, command line apps consist just the executable, while app bundles (.app) are actually directories containing the executable, and the Info.plist file (among others).

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55518922/1187415 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7797773/1187415 about how to embed an Info.plist in a command line tool.

Comment: post your real code `import foundation` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Martin R is comment i solved my problem by linking a new  plist file to the project