# Calling getsectiondata from Swift

Tags: swift, macos, mach-o

This question and answer describe how to read data from a Mach-O section with Objective-C on modern OS X/macOS versions: [Crash reading bytes from getsectbyname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978788/crash-reading-bytes-from-getsectbyname)

The described answer works. I'm trying to implement the same thing with Swift. I can't make it work.

I have the following in "Other linker flags": `-Wl,-sectcreate,__LOCALIZATIONS,__base,en.lproj/Localizable.strings,-segprot,__LOCALIZATIONS,r,r`.

This Swift code gets me the a pointer to the embedded data, until I try to run the code outside Xcode and ASLR breaks it:

```
var size: UInt = 0
let _localizationSection = getsectdata(
    "__LOCALIZATIONS",
    "__base",
    &size)
```

To get around the ASLR problem, according to the above question and answer, and based on my own testing, I should be using `getsectiondata` instead. It works great in Objective-C, but I'm having no luck in Swift. The following is the only thing I've managed to get past the compiler, but it returns nil:

```
var size: UInt = 0
var header = _mh_execute_header
let localizationSection = getsectiondata(
    &header,
    "__LOCALIZATIONS",
    "__base",
    &size)
```

Is taking a copy of `_mh_execute_header` the problem and is there any way to avoid it? I need an `UnsafePointer<mach_header_64>`, but using `&_mh_execute_header` as the first parameter to `getsectiondata` causes a compilation error.

I'm using Swift 3.0, and running my code on macOS 10.12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the linked-to Objective-C code

```
void *ptr = getsectiondata(&_mh_execute_header, ...);
```

and your Swift translation

```
var header = _mh_execute_header
let localizationSection = getsectiondata(&header, ...)
```

is that the latter passes the address of a *copy* of the global
`_mh_execute_header` variable to the function, and apparently that
is not accepted. If you modify the Objective-C code to

```
struct mach_header_64 header = _mh_execute_header;
void *ptr = getsectiondata(&header, ...);
```

then it fails as well (and actually crashed in my test).

Now the problem is that `_mh_execute_header` is exposed to Swift
as a *constant:*

```
public let _mh_execute_header: mach_header_64
```

and one cannot take the address of a constant in Swift. One possible
workaround is to define

```
#import <mach-o/ldsyms.h>
static const struct mach_header_64 *mhExecHeaderPtr = &_mh_execute_header;
```

in the bridging header file, and then use it as

```
let localizationSection = getsectiondata(mhExecHeaderPtr, ...)
```

in Swift.

---

Another option is to lookup the symbol via `dlopen`/`dlsym`

```
import MachO

if let handle = dlopen(nil, RTLD_LAZY) {
    defer { dlclose(handle) }

    if let ptr = dlsym(handle, MH_EXECUTE_SYM) {
        let mhExecHeaderPtr = ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: mach_header_64.self)

        var size: UInt = 0
        let localizationSection = getsectiondata(
            mhExecHeaderPtr,
            "__LOCALIZATIONS",
            "__base",
            &size)

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That reduces the amount of Objective-C I have to write and is a pretty decent solution if I already have a bridging header in the project, but is still a bit annoying in an otherwise pure Swift project.

Comment: @JuriPakaste: I have added another (pure Swift) solution.

Comment: @MartinR “one cannot take the address of a constant in Swift” … We can use `withUnsafePointer(to: _mh_execute_header)`, no?

Comment: @fumoboy007: Yes, that is new in Swift 4.x(?) – But I tried that and it does not work here for some reason. It compiles, but does not return the section data.