# How to access properties/member of struct pointer in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers, struct, dyld, mach-o

I am messing around with Mach-O Headers and dyld and came across this function `_dyld_get_image_header` that returns a pointer to the mach header of a dynamic library.

I thought I might be able to access the Mach-O segments of dynamic libraries through this pointer following [this article](https://h3adsh0tzz.com/2020/01/macho-file-format/). However, I am not able to access the properties of the Mach-O Headers and am getting errors . In the Swift code below, I attempted to access the ncmds or load command property of the struct and was met with an error:

```
var currentLibrary = 0
// Gets Pointer to Mach Header of First Dynamic Library, Index 0
let libHeader = unsafeBitCast(_dyld_get_image_header(UInt32(currentLibrary)), to: UnsafePointer<mach_header_64>.self)

print(libHeader.ncmds)
```

Error:

```
Value of type 'UnsafePointer<mach_header_64>' has no member 'ncmds'
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39732016/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to `c`, where you would use the `->` operator (`libHeader->ncmds`), requivalent to `(*libHeader).ncmds`. That is, first your reference the pointer to get to the `mach_header_64` value, then you access its `ncmds` field.

In Swift, it's the exact same idea, with different syntax: `libHeaver.pointee.ncmds`