# Retrieve the version of a macOS executable with an embedded Info.plist?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, executable

It's possible to embed an Info.plist section into an executable file for macOS.

An example is [this searchfs tool](https://files.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/searchfs.zip).

And if you Get Info in Finder for this file, it'll show the correct version info (here: 1.0.2).

How can I conveniently get this info in a macOS app (using ObjC or Swift)? I'd expect that `NSWorkspace` would offer such a function but it doesn't seem to.

I don't want to have to scan the file section myself in order to extract the `__info_plist` section. Is there a better way?

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7780789/77567) helpful. In particular, look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381340/77567) discussing `CFBundleCopyInfoDictionaryForURL`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had looked for such an answer but had no luck. This makes this one a duplicate, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, unless you need further helping.

Answer (score 1):

One can retrieve the contents of the embedded info.plist with this cmd:

```
otool -P /path/to/searchfs
```

Then you can convert that output into a plist (via the `CFPropertyList` API) and extract the value for the key `CFBundleShortVersionString`.

However, that is not an efficient way to parse many files in order to get their version numbers.